# Facebook setting "prompt visitors to send messages" is not sowing

Tags: facebook

I made a chatbot which i now integrated into my facebook page.

Like most pages I want facebook to open the messenger window so users can see they can use our chatbot.
You do this by enabling "prompt visitors to send messages".
Almost all websites state that setting must be enabled.

You find this setting normally in: Settings>Messaging>General Settings>”Prompt visitors to send messages”. The problem is that I can't see this setting.

I've searched for a while but didn't see anyone with this problem.

In the picture you can see the settings i see.

Thank you for your help!

[Facebook settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOI2k.png)

Answer (score 0):

Some people won’t have this settings. It’s not fair I know. Come back check in a month again and your Response Rate needs to be above 75%, so it is imperative that you respond to your inbox messages promptly.